# ASP.NET MVC - Organizing Site / URLs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My question is around the best practice for dividing up an asp.net mvc web app. I am building a fairly simple application which has two main sections, public and private. Basically I am running up against the issue of collisions between controllers. What I want is to have urls like /public/portfolio, but also have /private/portfolio.

Looking into some options, it seems that areas would work well for this situation. Are there other alternatives, such as some creative routing scheme that I should consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at ASP.NET MVC 2.0 areas

http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/aspnet-mvc-2---areas

That might do the trick.

Comment: I mentioned areas in my original question. I am looking to find out if this is the way to go, or if there are other solutions to consider.

Comment: I would go with Areas. I haven't seen any other ways that make a lot of sense and are as easy to implement.